# Display my profiles in rep order when I view my profile from the app's sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Here's a snap of my profile when I select it from the top of the left-hand drawer menu:

[image]

How does the app decide which three profiles of mine to show in that view? It makes sense to show MSE and SFF, because those are the sites where I have the most rep. But the app is not choosing my top three profiles by rep, otherwise Stack Overflow would be nowhere to be seen - it's 25th on my list at time of writing.

When you look at someone else's profile in the app, the first expanded line is their profile from the site you're currently on. After that, it displays the top two sites by rep (not including the one that's already been shown).

It seems that viewing my profile from the sidebar is behaving the same way, but in the absence of a "site you came from" to show first, the app is just choosing Stack Overflow. Instead, it should just show my top three sites in rep order.

Comment: Couldn't decide if this was a bug or a missing feature, so I picked one.

Comment: I think it picks the referring site (which is not defined for the access via the sidebar), defaulting to the profile on the oldest site (maybe?). Then the next two entries are the top two sites by reputation, excluding the first site. That it's not intuitive might be a sign it's too complicated. :P

Comment: Sounds right to me, @Tim. Not sure why having the referring site undefined defaults to SO, though.

Comment: @TimStone Same in the Android app, although I'm not sure about the bug with SO being the default referring site (I happen to have the most rep on SO so I can't check).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The network profile screen takes a `(user,site)` pair as input parameters.  It uses these values to A) get the network user ID and B) prioritize the user in the listing, displaying the right name, icon, and that site first in the list.  When coming from a link on a site view, this makes sense.

On the personal profile view it takes `(user,site)` as well for simplicity.  The failure point is that we were just grabbing the first result from [`/users/{ids}/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=459488&types=main_site&filter=!6OijEr5gpCuM)&run=true) which does not have a clear sort order.

I've updated the code to use your highest rep site throughout the app (with a little extra logic to calm randomness).